# Graphics Messages while running LightTable on 14.04 x64

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, opengl

I'm new to Ubuntu, and receive the following issues when running Juno within LightTable:

```
marktab@ubuntu0617:~$ ./LightTable/LightTable  markab@ubuntu0617:~$
[2883:0504/161921:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(226)] Gdk:
gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large libGL error: pci id for fd
11: 80ee:beef, driver (null) OpenGL Warning: glFlushVertexArrayRangeNV
not found in mesa table OpenGL Warning: glVertexArrayRangeNV not found
in mesa table OpenGL Warning: glCombinerInputNV not found in mesa
table OpenGL Warning: glCombinerOutputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfNV not found in mesa table OpenGL
Warning: glCombinerParameterfvNV not found in mesa table OpenGL
Warning: glCombinerParameteriNV not found in mesa table OpenGL
Warning: glCombinerParameterivNV not found in mesa table OpenGL
Warning: glFinalCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table OpenGL
Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa
table OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterfvNV not found in
mesa table OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterivNV not found
in mesa table OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterfvNV not
found in mesa table OpenGL Warning:
glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table OpenGL
Warning: glDeleteFencesNV not found in mesa table OpenGL Warning:
glFinishFenceNV not found in mesa table OpenGL Warning: glGenFencesNV
not found in mesa table OpenGL Warning: glGetFenceivNV not found in
mesa table OpenGL Warning: glIsFenceNV not found in mesa table OpenGL
Warning: glSetFenceNV not found in mesa table OpenGL Warning:
glTestFenceNV not found in mesa table libGL error: core dri or dri2
extension not found libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by
environment. OpenGL Warning: glXChooseFBConfig returning NULL, due to
attrib=0x2, next=0x20 [2911:0504/161923:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(555)]
glXChooseFBConfig failed.
[2911:0504/161923:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(27)]
gfx::GLContext::CreateOffscreenGLSurface failed
[2911:0504/161923:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(142)] InitializeSandbox()
called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
[2911:0504/161923:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(313)]
[.ChromiumCompositor-0x22a2aa119c40]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM :
glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
```

I am running inside VirtualBox and have 3D graphics acceleration turned on (host NVidia drivers are current -- host system has Intel video too). The issue may be my Ubuntu: any pointers welcome.